# Spring boot @ConfigurationProperties not loaded

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configurationproperty

As the title says, I'm trying to use [Typesafe Configuration Properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) to load a list of `DataSourceConfig` objects. I have lombok for setter/getters

The main application class annotations

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Application {
```

The configuration pojo

```
@Data
public class DataSourceConfig {
    private String key;
    private String dbname;
    private String dbpath;
}
```

The yml file

```
tenantdb:
    dataSourceConfig:
        -
            key: default 
            dbpath: file:eventstore/jdbc/database
            dbname: defaultdb
        -
            key: other
            dbpath: file:eventstore/jdbc/other
            dbname: dslfjsdf
```

Finally, the Spring Configuration class with the @ConfigurationProperties annotation.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("hsqldb")
@ImportResource(value = { "persistence-config.xml" })
@Slf4j
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="tenantdb", locations={"datasources.yml"})
public class HsqlConfiguration {


    private List<DataSourceConfig> dataSourceConfig = new ArrayList<>();

    @Bean
    public List<DataSourceConfig> getDataSourceConfig() {
        return dataSourceConfig;
    }
```

With the config above, I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hsqlConfiguration': Could not bind properties to [unknown] (target=tenantdb, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initia
```

I've tried various combinations. If I change the annotation to `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="tenantdb.dataSourceConfig")`, I don't get the error but `List<DataSourceConfig>` is empty.

HELP!!

Comment: My configuration properties are annotated with `@Component` and it gets filled while component scanning, have you tried that? Also two more things, where is `datasources.yml` located and why is `getDataSourceConfig` annotated as bean?

Comment: `datasources.yml` is at the classpath root. `getDataSourceConfig` is annotated as a bean so that I can inject it elsewhere as well.

Comment: I tried to play around with your code, created test and I get list of 2 `DataSourceConfig` as expected. Only thing is that they are empty (have `null` for `key`, `dbname` and `dbpath`. I provided setters on that class and it binded fine, might be that?

Comment: Can you put `ignoreUnknownFields = false` and check what you get?

Comment: Did you try with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="tenantdb.dataSourceConfig")`? I put `ignoreUnknownFields` - no difference in behavior? For the binding behavior  - I have lombok - so setters/getters are generated.

Comment: Might be some lombok - spring boot collision, I tried with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="tenantdb", locations={"datasources.yml"})` and it works as expected, only thing I do not want to add lombok so used regular setter/getters. Also I had problems when I placed yml file in /config location but when I placed it to `src/main/resources` it started working

Comment: What's your version of spring-boot? I'm on 1.2.1.RELEASE. I get an NPE with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="tenantdb", locations={"datasources.yml"})` :( - at this location `at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.extendCollectionIfNecessary(RelaxedDataBinder.java:248)`

Comment: Can you upload your code someplace? I'm at my wit's end with this :(

Comment: A `@ConfigurationProperties` bean is meant to be a simple pojo. All these annotations you added on it seems like the wrong place to me. Your `@Bean` on `DataSourceConfig` is definitely wrong. Please move only the configuration part to a bean with just `@ConfigurationProperites` on it. Lombok is supported.

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll Removing the @Bean from `DataSourceConfig` was the problem - getting rid of that fixed it; Now I inject the HsqlConfiguration itself into other places where I need the config and things seem to be working. If you can create an answer, I'll accept it; Also can you let me know which ones specifically look wrong = annotation wise? I probably have to restructure a bit; @Nenad - Thanks for your help as well

Comment: As I said in first comment you should probably make `TenantDbProperties` which are just `@Component` and  `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="tenantdb", locations={"datasources.yml"})` and are simple pojo as @StéphaneNicoll suggested and have  `HsqlConfiguration` with other configuration and component scan on package where properties are

Comment: @NenadBozic, make your responses into answers so that we can accept.

Comment: My answer was from March so I will try but correct me if I am wrong since it was while ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use configuration properties as simple POJO with only getters and setters and have separate `HsqlConfiguration` which has this properties injected.

Something like this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="tenantdb", locations={"datasources.yml"})
public class TenantDbProperties {

  //DataSourceConfig is POJO with key, dbpath and dbname
  private List<DataSourceConfig> dataSourceConfigs;       

  public List<DataSourceConfig> getDataSourceConfigs(){
      return dataSourceConfigs;
  }

  public void setDataSourceConfigs(List<DataSourceConfig> dataSourceConfigs){
      this.dataSourceConfigs = dataSourceConfigs;
  }
}
```

And in separate class have this properties injected as:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("hsqldb")
@ImportResource(value = { "persistence-config.xml" })
@Slf4j
public class HsqlConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private TenantDbProperties tenantDbProperties;

    //code goes here where you can use tenantDbProperties.getDataSourceConfigs()
}
```